# how to access variables inside app.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I access a variable or set of variables inside app.get and make it accessible to the whole project? I am trying to capture the information sent from the SMS text, organized into the "messageData" variable, then sent to the "MessageSchema," where it is then sent and stored in the Mongo Database. My issue is that I believe none of the variables(message, number, answer) are truly being found. How can I fix that?

app.js

```
app.get('/smssent', function(req, res, callback) {
var message = req.query.Body;
var number = req.query.From;
var twilioNumber = req.query.To;

var context = null;
var index = 0;
var contextIndex = 0;
contexts.forEach(function(value)
{
  console.log(value.from);
  if (value.from == number)
  {
    context = value.context;
    contextIndex = index;
  }
  index = index + 1;
});

console.log('Recieved message from ' + number + ' saying \'' + message  + '\'');

var conversation = new ConversationV1({
  username: '',
  password: '',
  version_date: ConversationV1.VERSION_DATE_2016_09_20
});

//console.log(JSON.stringify(context));
//console.log(contexts.length);

conversation.message({
  input: { text: message },
  workspace_id: '',
  context: context
 }, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
     } else {
      var answer = response.output.text[0];

if (context == null) {
         contexts.push({'from': number, 'context': response.context});
       } else {
         contexts[contextIndex].context = response.context;
       }

       var intent = response.intents[0].intent;
       console.log(intent);
       if (intent == "done") {
         //contexts.splice(contexts.indexOf({'from': number, 'context': response.context}),1);
         contexts.splice(contextIndex,1);
         // Call REST API here (order pizza, etc.)
       }

       var client = require('twilio')(
         '',
         ''
       );

       client.messages.create({
         from: twilioNumber,
         to: number,
         body: response.output.text[0]
       }, function(err, message) {
         if(err) {
           console.error(err.message);
         }
       });
     }
});

  res.send('');
});
```

(ABOVE)This is what retrieves the SMS text, and conducts Twilio, Node, and IBM Bluemix.

index.js

```
router.post('/app', function(req, res, next) {
if (req.body.number &&
  req.body.message &&
  req.body.answer
) {
  // create object with form input
  var messageData = {
    number: req.body.number,
    message: req.body.message,
    answer: req.body.answer
  };

  // use schema's `create` method to insert document into Mongo
  Message.create(messageData, function (error, message) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
  });

} else {
  var err = new Error('All fields required.');
  err.status = 400;
  return next(err);
}
});
```

(ABOVE)This is the code to organize and prepare everything for the "MessageSchema."

message.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  number: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  answer: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);
module.exports = Message;
```

Finally, this is what sends all the info to the DB.

If anyone finds anything or has any tips to improve this code, please let me know, I am open for all the input you can give me!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var messageData = {
    number: req.body.number,
    message: req.body.message,
    answer: req.body.answer
  };
```

This is OK. However, keep in mind that these variables are sent through POST body, not queries like the other one.

```
queries: ?param = ...
body: (like POST form; hidden from the URL)
```

If you unsure whether you are passing them alright, you can test that easily by `console.info(...)` on a certain point; and using Postman to easily test POST behavior.

Comment: Great Thanks, I will look into that! I'm not sure how deep you looked into those code samples but, did you by chance notice anything else that may have been causing the lack of posting in the DB?